# How can I improve my closed question and how to address multiple questions in a narrow context?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed, quality-improvement

What's wrong with my question *[Am I using GetFinalPathNameByHandle (Windows API) in my Delphi program correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69430755/am-i-using-getfinalpathnamebyhandle-windows-api-in-my-delphi-program-correctly)* (now only visible to users above 10,000 reputation points)?

I understand we should focus our questions as much as possible, but my first revision asked four concise things about my implementation in a list. Yes, I could do it in a paragraph instead, but with my experience people tend to only address part of the question that way. I honestly don't see posting four different questions with 95% the same text (I'm pretty sure it would be closed as duplicate anyway).

I'm just trying to improve myself here.

Comment: The revised question seems like it would be better on Code Review.

Comment: The end of your question says "*Do you see anything bad or that could be better with my implementation?*" That's basically asking for a review of your code. If it's a couple of lines of code, and you specify the issues there might be in the code, it would be reasonable, so maybe you could try focusing on a specific part of the code?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are both right it's a better fit for SE Code Review...

Comment: If you do decide to post on Code Review, make sure to read the help pages, and how-to-ask page for *that* site before posting. The community on that site is not fond (and rightly so) of users posting questions there simply because it's not a good fit here, and the fact that you're asking for a code review. That site has it's own standards (like every site on this network), and you need to follow them as well.